# Unable to resolve NoClassDefFoundError for Jena IRIFactory

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jena, rdfa

Below is the stacktrace of the error log I'm getting. If someone can tell what exactly could be causing this because as per the stacktrace I've everything in place.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory
    at net.rootdev.javardfa.uri.IRIResolver.<init>(IRIResolver.java:26)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.rdfa.SAXRDFaParser.createInstance(SAXRDFaParser.java:57)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.initialize(OdfFileDom.java:217)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.initialize(OdfManifestDom.java:74)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.<init>(OdfFileDom.java:132)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.<init>(OdfManifestDom.java:63)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.newFileDom(OdfFileDom.java:189)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.parseManifest(OdfPackage.java:1219)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.readZip(OdfPackage.java:452)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.initializeZip(OdfPackage.java:422)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.<init>(OdfPackage.java:250)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.loadPackage(OdfPackage.java:320)
    at org.odftoolkit.simple.Document.loadDocument(Document.java:328)
    at org.odftoolkit.simple.TextDocument.loadDocument(TextDocument.java:305)
    at com.poc.LetsGetStarted.main(LetsGetStarted.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRIFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

**Jar Versions : jena-iri : 1.0.2 , java-rdfa : 0.4**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the reason, I've tried both java-rdfa version 0.4 and 0.5 snapshot but both of them refer to `com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRIFactory`, however in the current packaging IRIFactory is moved to package `org.apache.jena.iri.IRIFactory`.

Comment: Jena moved to Apache some time ago;  it's probably better to update to later versions that have the new packaging if possible.  If this worked for you, be sure to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @dShringi : Could you share how you resovled the issue? Did you just use an older version of jena or did you come up with a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: @claus I had to use the older version of jena, because odftoolkit's latest version has this dependency on the older version.

Comment: Just a short follow up: As the dependencies in odftoolkit drove me crazy I decided to take another route and chose http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/ . I am very happy with it: only one extra jar, all other dependencies can be installed with apt in Ubuntu. The documentation is somewhat thin but you can figure it out rather quickly from the unit tests and sample document templates. I would recommend it to anyone trying to get an odf template filled in java.

Answer (score 1):

com/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory class is not in any of the JARs specified in the class path.

To find the whether the class IRIFactory is in any of the jar files in the CLASS_PATH 
1) In windows extract each jar file and check for the class name
2) In linux use "jar -tvf [jar-file-name] |grep "IRIFactory"

If none of the jar contains the class file, add the correct jar in the class path.